# Como detectar a colisão com o chão SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl, detecção-de-colisão

Eu estou desenvolvendo um jogo para aprendizado usando C++ com SDL2, e quero verificar quando meu personagem toca o chão. Para isso criei a classe "Collider", com a seguinte função (adaptada):

```
bool isCollinding (SDL_Rect a, SDL_Rect b)
{
  if(a.x > b.x + b.w || // Esquerda de A a direita do lado direito de B
     a.x + a.w < b.x || // Direita de A a esquerda do lado esquerdo de B
     a.y > b.y + b.h || // Topo de A abaixo da base de B
     a.y + a.h < b.y)   // Base de A acima do topo de B
  {
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Porém, com esse método, só consigo saber se está colidindo, mas não sei se é a parte de baixo ou etc.
Como poderia saber se o que está colidindo é a parte de baixo de forma fácil?

Comment: Eu ia te enviar um link de uma colisão que eu detecto isso, mas aí eu me lembrei que é de círculo com retângulo... e em Python, TKinter. Interessa?

Comment: Normalmente, quando meus colegas vão fazer um jogo 2D como exercício, eles colocam um colisor (na verdade, colisor modo `trigger` na Unity) na parte inferior do objeto, o que simplifica o algoritmo usado para saber de onde vem o impacto

Comment: Python me interessa, mas nunca trabalhei com, então não tenho conhecimento nenhum do assunto. Usar um **trigger** é uma boa ideia, eu posso tentar.

Comment: Procurar por `colidiu`: https://github.com/jeffque/games-tk-breakout/blob/master/breakout/geometry.py

Comment: Essa solução que eu te mandei no link não faz uso de `trigger`, apenas do colisor e da bolinha